How can I center the output of general R results in Quarto?
In a Quarto document that creates HTML output, I can print general R object and the results will be left aligned in Quarto. How can I center or right align general R objects?  In addition, is there a way I could add a gray background to this output?
The code provided is from a default template Quarto file, and the image shows the results being left aligned by default.
```{r}
mtcars
```



What's the desired output format of the quarto document?

Thanks for the clarifying question. HTML is the desired output format.

Extending from this answer,
---
title: "Test"
format: html
css: style.css
---

```{r}
#| classes: styled-output
mtcars
```


style.css
.styled-output .cell-output {
  background-color: #c8cac8;
}

.styled-output .cell-output pre {
  max-width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}



Thanks as always @shafee! Where can I learn more about the construction of this CSS definition? I'd like to further modify the font size and font color

@kputschko, uuhh there are so many places for learning css that it is really tough to suggest a place, at least for me. I simply google stuff. And also there are gpt models now.
